# hive job hangs when inserting data to a partitioned table

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

All other queries work for me.  Only when I try inserting data into a partioned table from a normal table, it hangs.

```
insert overwrite table ipconp partition(country) select ip,country from ipcon;
Query ID = hadoop_20160924000433_49d65106-240f-45b2-bbb7-d681473269cc
Total jobs = 3
Launching Job 1 out of 3
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_1473747226110_0013, Tracking URL = http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1473747226110_0013/
Kill Command = /work/hadoop-2.6.0/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1473747226110_0013
```